# PHP session form submit condition

Tags: forms, php

i am trying to store session value and check if fields are filled proceed the form function else back to signup form.

but am getting error for below line.

```
if(($_SESSION['name'] == '') && ($_SESSION['email'] == '') && ($_SESSION['phone'] == ''))
```

and below is the full php code which am using in the form page.

```
<?php 

session_start(); 

   if (isset($_POST['signup']))  
    {

    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];
    }


    if(($_SESSION['name'] == '') && ($_SESSION['email'] == '') && ($_SESSION['phone'] == ''))
        {
        exit(); 
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location : signup-form.php');
        exit();     
    }



 ?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the best one

```
<?php 

session_start(); 

   if (isset($_POST['signup']))  
    {

    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];
    }


    if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){ // if name is empty
        exit('Type your name.'); 
    }elseif(!isset($_SESSION['email'])){ // if email is empty
        exit('Type your email.'); 
    }elseif(!isset($_SESSION['phone'])){ // if phone number is empty
        exit('Type your phone.'); 
    }else{ // ohh look, they're all fine
        header('Location : signup-form.php');
        exit();     
    } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

when using header remove spaces from your code and then use `isset()` to check that session is set or not

```
<?php 
 session_start(); 
   if (isset($_POST['signup']))  
    {

    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];
    }
   if(!isset($_SESSION['name']) && !isset($_SESSION['email']) && !isset($_SESSION['phone']))
        {
        exit(); 
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location : signup-form.php');
        exit();     
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for the SESSION before it's set using **[isset()](http://www.php.net/isset)**

The correct way is:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['name']) && !isset($_SESSION['email']) && !isset($_SESSION['phone'])){
  exit();
}
else{
 //...
}
```